# Two uncountable sets A and B are countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble finding the solution to the following problem...

Give an example of an uncountable set $A$ and an uncountable set $B$ such that $A$ intersect $B$ is countable infinite.

Answer - I know that $(-\infty, 1]$ and $[1, \infty)$ has an intersection of $\{1\}$. $\{1\}$ is countable but $\{1\}$ is also finite. I need to find two sets that have a result of countably infinite. Thanks guys!

Comment: please use latex :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT:** Can you find two uncountable sets which are disjoint? Now find a countable set and add it to both of them.

Comment: The intersection of the two disjoint sets would be an empty set, and wouldn't that be not uncountable? So I wouldn't have two uncountable sets anymore right?

Comment: Read it again...

Comment: aii broski, thanks I gotta wait 3 mins to accept

Comment: @user2933041: Now that you’ve worked it out, here’s a moderately natural example: $A=\Bbb R\times\Bbb Q$ and $B=\Bbb Q\times\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Brian: substitute the $\times$ for $\cup$. Does it still hold (take B to be Q times B_1, the set of binary sequences)

Comment: @DonLarynx: I’m not sure what your $A$ is.

Comment: @Brian: Let $A$ be $\Bbb{I} \cup \Bbb{Q}$ and $B$ be $\Bbb{B} \cup \Bbb{Q}$. $\Bbb{I}$ is the set of irrationals and $\Bbb{B}$ is the set of infinite binary sequences. Does this work?

Comment: @DonLarynx: Yes, that works; it’s an instance of the method that Asaf suggested in his hint.